# Can I associate a connection string with an endpoint in WCF?

Tags: wcf, web-services, rest, .net-4.0, web-config

We have a WCF REST service that connects to a database.  In fact, we have several instances of the database, all with the same schema.

We would like to set up one endpoint for each database instance and associate a connection string with the endpoint.  The service would read the connection string and connect to the appropriate SQL Server instance.

I'm sure this is possible; is it a good idea?  How do I set it up?  Is there documentation on MSDN?

**Edit:** I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718537/dynamically-adding-wcf-data-services-endpoints), where the answer suggests adding connection information on the client in a header.  I don't want to do that—for security reasons, and because I *do* want to have a distinct uri for each database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bit harder than I thought.  WCF has *so many* extensibility points its hard to pick the right one.  Please answer or comment if you think there's a better way, or anything wrong with this.

I've settled on using a custom class that implements [IEndpointBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iendpointbehavior.aspx) and [IDispatchMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector.aspx).  I have a class derived from [BehaviorExtensionElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.behaviorextensionelement.aspx) that lets me associate the behavior with an endpoint in configuration.  [This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/06/28/wcf-extensibility-behavior-configuration-extensions.aspx) describes hot do do that.

My `DatabaseConnectionContext` class looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// An endpoint behavior that associates a database connection string name with the endpoint and adds it to the
/// properties of incoming messages.
/// </summary>
public class DatabaseConnectionContext : IEndpointBehavior, IDispatchMessageInspector
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DatabaseConnectionContext"/> class with the provided connection string name.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connectionStringName">The name of the connection string to associate with the endpoint.</param>
    public DatabaseConnectionContext(string connectionStringName)
    {
        this.ConnectionStringName = connectionStringName;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the name of the connection string to associate with the endpoint.
    /// </summary>
    public string ConnectionStringName { get; private set; }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
    {
        endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(this);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        request.Properties["connectionStringName"] = this.ConnectionStringName;
        return null;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
    }
}
```

In my service class I have this method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the connection string to use for this service call.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A SQL Server database connection string.</returns>
    private string GetConnectionString()
    {
        string connectionStringName = (string)OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageProperties["connectionStringName"];
        return ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName].ConnectionString;
    }
```

My `BehaviorExtensionElement` class looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Associates a <see cref="DatabaseConnectionContext"/> with an endpoint in configuration.
/// </summary>
public class DatabaseConnectionContextBehaviorExtension : BehaviorExtensionElement
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the <see cref="ConnectionStringName"/> property when it appears in a configuration file.
    /// </summary>
    private const string ConnectionStringNamePropertyName = "connectionStringName";

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the name of the configuration string to associate with the endpoint.
    /// </summary>
    [ConfigurationProperty(ConnectionStringNamePropertyName)]
    public string ConnectionStringName
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)this[ConnectionStringNamePropertyName];
        }

        set
        {
            this[ConnectionStringNamePropertyName] = value;
        }
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    public override Type BehaviorType
    {
        get { return typeof(DatabaseConnectionContext); }
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    protected override object CreateBehavior()
    {
        return new DatabaseConnectionContext(this.ConnectionStringName);
    }
}
```

My web.config contains something like this:

```
<behaviors>

  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DevRestEndpointConfiguration">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="false" />
      <connectionStringInterceptor connectionStringName="myDevConnectionStringName" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="ProductionRestEndpointConfiguration">
      <webHttp helpEnabled="false" />
      <connectionStringInterceptor connectionStringName="myProductionConnectionStringName" />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

</behaviors>

<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="connectionStringInterceptor" type="DatabaseConnectionContextBehaviorExtension, MyAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
```

Each `<endpoint />` element in the `<services />` section has its `behaviorConfiguration` set to the name of an appropriate element from the `<endpointBehaviors />` section.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you add a new parameters specifying what is the database the call will connect?

for example:

- you can add a `db` parameters that will get a number and from there you will connect
- you can add such parameter on the authentication method

as the example for the first item:

```
public ProductItem GetProduct(int productId, int db = 1)
{
    ProductItem product = new ProductItem();
    string connectionString = getConnectionStringForDb(db);

    using (SqlConnection connection =
        new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT name, price FROM Products WHERE productId = @product;", connection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product", productId);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();

            product = new product({
                Name = reader[0],
                Price = reader[1]
            });

            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log exception
        }
    }

    return product;
}
```

taken [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx)

```
private string getConnectionStringForDb(int type)
{

    System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings connString;
    System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/MyWebSiteRoot");

    if (rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Count > 0) {

        connString = rootWebConfig.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString_" + type];

        if (connString == null) {
            // LOG ERROR
        }
    }
    return connString.ConnectionString;
}
```

and just add your connection strings in your `web.config` and name then like:

```
DBConnectionString_1, DBConnectionString_2, DBConnectionString_3
```

or anything that makes sense to you.

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add 
    name="DBConnectionString_1" 
    connectionString="Data Source=serverName;Initial 
    Catalog=Northwind;Persist Security Info=True;User 
    ID=userName;Password=password"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
  />
  <add 
    name="DBConnectionString_2" 
    connectionString="Data Source=serverName;Initial 
    Catalog=Northwind;Persist Security Info=True;User 
    ID=userName;Password=password"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
  />
  <add 
    name="DBConnectionString_3" 
    connectionString="Data Source=serverName;Initial 
    Catalog=Northwind;Persist Security Info=True;User 
    ID=userName;Password=password"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
  />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: I quite like this suggestion. It works well for REST services where part of the URI can easily be passes as a parameter to the service method.  However, I've gone with a different solution—see my own reply—since I think it'll work better if we expose a SOAP endpoint later. Also, we don't necessarily want every connection string that appears in web.config to be available.

Answer (score 0):

With this in your web.config:

```
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="Foo.svc" value="tagvalue1"/>
  </appSettings>
  ...
```

You could retrieve the value at runtime this way:

```
    private static string GetConfigValue()
    {
        ServiceEndpointCollection ec = OperationContext.Current
            .Host.Description.Endpoints;
        if (ec!=null)
        {
            var segments = ec[0].Address.ToString().Split('/');
            var s = segments[segments.Length-1]; // "Foo.svc"
            return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[s]; // "tagvalue1"
        } 
        return null;
    }
```